# grails: scss compiler required for production env

Tags: grails, vaadin

Using Vaadin7 with grails, i'm facing an issue to get the production mode working:

```
Dec 25, 2013 11:56:28 PM com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet serveOnTheFlyCompiledScss
INFO: Request for /VAADIN/themes/app/styles.css not handled by sass compiler while in production mode
```

Which is normal since no scss compiler to css is set by default for prod unlike to dev mode.

I'm looking for a grails hack in order to get the equivalent of the maven tool for prod war generation:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
                <mainClass>com.vaadin.sass.SassCompiler</mainClass>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/app/styles.scss</argument>
                    <argument>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/app/styles.css</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: isn't it compiled on `grails war`?

Comment: Just compiled with "prod war"

Comment: No workaround found, how to force the dev mode resources for production ?

Comment: I always ran "java -cp '/Users/ondrej/frameworks/vaadin-all-7.0.0/*' com.vaadin.sass.SassCompiler styles.scss styles.css" But I do agree it should be part of prod war target in Grails. I made a new issue here: https://github.com/ondrej-kvasnovsky/grails-vaadin-plugin/issues/17

Comment: Great to hear that Ondrej. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added support for SASS compilation. It is available from 7.1.9.1 plugin version. It downloads needed libraries and executes SASS compilation when running war command for prod environment. Just run "grails prod war" and it will run the compilation. [More info in this tutorial](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Vaadin%20on%20Grails%20-%20SASS%20Compilation).

Answer (score 2):

As you can see here https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/3281129, you can do

"What we do is before we do the release, we run in debug mode so that SASS compiler automatically runs, and then we use our browser to request the URL /WEBAPPNAME/VAADIN/themes/YOURTHEMENAME/styles.css -- the compiler automatically runs and generates the styles.css for display in your browser, and then you can just save that file for release."